# Unit test macro

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, common-lisp, macros

I have written a couple of macros (`?` and `??`) for performing unit tests, but I'm having some difficulty with modifying it, so I was hoping to get some feedback on how to tidy up what I have written so far.

*Yes, I know that unit test frameworks already exist, but I'm trying to learn by doing.*

Here is an example of usage:

```
(??
  (? "Arithmetic tests"
    (? "Addition"
        (= (+ 1 2) 3)
        (= (+ 1 2 3) 6)
        (= (+ -1 -3) -4))))
```

And an example of output:

> ```
> [Arithmetic tests]
>   [Addition]
>     (PASS) '(= (+ 1 2) 3)'
>     (PASS) '(= (+ 1 2 3) 6)'
>     (PASS) '(= (+ -1 -3) -4)'
>
> Results: 3 tests passed, 0 tests failed
> ```

Now, the existing code works. Unfortunately, the `(? ...)` macro implementation is ugly, verbose, resistant to change - and I'm pretty sure also badly structured. For example, do I really have to use a list to store pieces of output code and then emit the contents at the end?

I'd like to modify the macro to permit description strings (or symbols) to optionally follow each test, whereupon it would replace the test literal in the output, thus:

```
(??
  (? "Arithmetic tests"
    (? "Addition"
        (= (+ 1 2) 3)    "Adding 1 and 2 results in 3"
        (= (+ 1 2 3) 6)
        (= (+ -1 -3) -4))))
```

Output:

> ```
> [Arithmetic tests]
>   [Addition]
>     (PASS) Adding 1 and 2 results in 3
>     (PASS) '(= (+ 1 2 3) 6)'
>     (PASS) '(= (+ -1 -3) -4)'
> ```

But unfortunately I can't find a sensible place in the macro to insert this change. Depending on where I put it, I get errors like *you're not inside a backquote expression*, *label is not defined* or *body-forms is not defined*. I know what these errors mean, but I can't find a way to avoid them.

Also, I'll be wanting to handle exceptions thrown during the test, and treat that as a failure. Currently, there is no exception handling code - the test result is merely tested against `nil`. Again, it is not clear how I should add this functionality.

I'm thinking that maybe this macro is over-complex, due to my inexperience in writing macros; and perhaps if I simplify it, modification will be easier. I don't really want to separate it out into several smaller macros without good reason; but maybe there's a terser way to write it?

A complete code listing follows:

```
; Support functions and macros:
(defmacro with-gensyms ((&rest names) &body body)
    `(let ,(loop for n in names collect `(,n (gensym)))
         ,@body))

(defmacro while (condition &body body)
    `(loop while ,condition do (progn ,@body)))

(defun flatten (L)
  "Converts a list to single level."
  (if (null L)
    nil
    (if (atom (first L))
      (cons (first L) (flatten (rest L)))
      (append (flatten (first L)) (flatten (rest L))))))

(defun starts-with-p (str1 str2)
  "Determine whether `str1` starts with `str2`"
  (let ((p (search str2 str1)))
    (and p (= 0 p))))

(defmacro pop-first-char (string)
    `(with-gensyms (c)
        (if (> (length ,string) 0)
            (progn
                (setf c (schar ,string 0))
                (if (> (length ,string) 1)
                    (setf ,string (subseq ,string 1))
                    (setf ,string ""))))
    c))

(defmacro pop-chars (string count)
    `(with-gensyms (result)
        (setf result ())
        (dotimes (index ,count)
            (push (pop-first-char ,string) result))
        result))

(defun format-ansi-codes (text)
    (let ((result ()))
        (while (> (length text) 0)
            (cond
                ((starts-with-p text "\\e")
                    (push (code-char #o33) result)
                    (pop-chars text 2)
                )
                ((starts-with-p text "\\r")
                    (push (code-char 13) result)
                    (pop-chars text 2)
                )
                (t (push (pop-first-char text) result))
        ))
        (setf result (nreverse result))
        (coerce result 'string)))

(defun kv-lookup (values key)
    "Like getf, but works with 'keys as well as :keys, in both the list and the supplied key"
    (setf key (if (typep key 'cons) (nth 1 key) key))
    (while values
        (let ((k (pop values)) (v (pop values)))
            (setf k (if (typep k 'cons) (nth 1 k) k))
            (if (eql (symbol-name key) (symbol-name k))
                (return v)))))

(defun make-ansi-escape (ansi-name)
    (let ((ansi-codes '( :normal "\\e[00m" :white "\\e[1;37m" :light-grey "\\e[0;37m" :dark-grey "\\e[1;30m"
                                    :red "\\e[0;31m" :light-red "\\e[1;31m" :green "\\e[0;32m" :blue "\\e[1;34m" :dark-blue "\\e[1;34m"
                                    :cyan "\\e[1;36m" :magenta "\\e[1;35m" :yellow "\\e[0;33m"
                                    :bg-dark-grey "\\e[100m"
                                    :bold "\\e[1m" :underline "\\e[4m"
                                    :start-of-line "\\r" :clear-line "\\e[2K" :move-up "\\e[1A")))
    (format-ansi-codes (kv-lookup ansi-codes ansi-name))
    ))

(defun format-ansi-escaped-arg (out-stream arg)
    (cond
        ((typep arg 'symbol) (format out-stream "~a" (make-ansi-escape arg)))
        ((typep arg 'string) (format out-stream arg))
        (t (format out-stream "~a" arg))
    ))

(defun format-ansi-escaped (out-stream &rest args)
    (while args
        (let ((arg (pop args)))
            (if (typep arg 'list)
                (let ((first-arg (eval (first arg))))
                    (format out-stream first-arg (second arg))
                )
                (format-ansi-escaped-arg out-stream arg)
        ))
    ))

(defmacro while-pop ((var sequence &optional result-form) &rest forms)
    (with-gensyms (seq)
        `(let (,var)
            (progn
                (do () ((not ,sequence))
                    (setf ,var (pop ,sequence))
                    (progn ,@forms))
                ,result-form))))

(defun report-start (form)
    (format t "(    ) '~a'~%" form))

(defun report-result (result form)
        (format-ansi-escaped t "(" (if result :green :red) `("~:[FAIL~;PASS~]" ,result) :normal `(") '~a'~%" ,form))
        result)

; Macro relevant to the question
(defmacro ? (name &body body-forms)
    "Run any number of test forms, optionally nested within further (?) calls, and print the results of each test"
    (with-gensyms (result indent indent-string)
        (if (not body-forms)
            :empty
            (progn
                (setf result () indent 0 indent-string "  ")
                (cond
                    ((typep (first body-forms) 'integer)
                        (setf indent (pop body-forms))))
                `(progn
                    (format t "~v@{~A~:*~}" ,indent ,indent-string)
                    (format-ansi-escaped t "[" :white ,name :normal "]~%")
                    (with-gensyms (test-results)
                        (setf test-results ())
                        ,(while-pop (body-form body-forms `(progn ,@(nreverse result)))
                            (cond
                                ( (EQL (first body-form) '?)
                                    (push `(progn
                                        (setf test-results (append test-results (? ',(nth 1 body-form) ,(1+ indent) ,@(nthcdr 2 body-form))))
                                        (format t "~%")
                                        test-results
                                    ) result)
                                )
                                (t
                                    (push `(progn
                                        (format t "~v@{~A~:*~}" ,(1+ indent) ,indent-string)
                                        (report-start ',body-form)
                                        (with-gensyms (result label)
                                            (setf result ,body-form)
                                            (format-ansi-escaped t :move-up :start-of-line :clear-line)
                                            (format t "~v@{~A~:*~}" ,(1+ indent) ,indent-string)
                                            (push (report-result result ',body-form) test-results)
                                            test-results
                                    )) result))))))))))

(defun ?? (&rest results)
    "Run any number of tests, and print a summary afterward"
    (setf results (flatten results))
    (format-ansi-escaped t "~&" :white "Results: " :green `("~a test~:p passed" ,(count t results)) :normal ", "
        (if (find NIL results) :red :normal) `("~a test~:p failed" ,(count NIL results))
        :yellow `("~[~:;, ~:*~a test~:p not run~]" ,(count :skip results))
        :brown `("~[~:;, ~:*~a empty test group~:p skipped~]" ,(count :empty results))
        :normal "~%"))
```

How could I improve this so that I can make modifications easier?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The way your question is worded  is likely to make it not very well received. The goal of any code review is not to help you change it or implement new features, but rather to improve your working code as it is. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I voted to reopen this, because it seems to me the main question is "How could I improve this so that I can make modifications easier?" More often than not, any improvements lead to improved flexibility and modifiability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite figure out which mode you're using for indentation,
suffice to say that standard `lisp-mode` indents this a bit differently,
but never mind that.  The single-line parenthesis really shouldn't be
there though, makes it look more ugly than necessary.

It's nice that the code is self-sufficient, though just in case that
that's not clear:  There are general-purpose helper libraries (for
something like `with-gensyms` etc.) as well as for ANSI escape
formatting available.

Btw. while the colour formatting might be nice, there should be a switch
to turn it off and it would be even nicer if it could detect when it
wasn't running in the shell, so that using e.g. SLIME i wouldn't have to
see garbage on the screen.

In general, macro arguments shouldn't be evaluated multiple times!  That
is the case for all macros where you currently use one of the arguments
more than once with `,` in the produced body.  Reworking that to bind to
a temporary variable first also ensures that passing in a literal will
work.  If you intent to modify a place, clearly indicate that in the
documentation, the macro argument names and still only evaluate the
initial value once.  Otherwise you'll either end up having bugs or less
then ideal performance due to repeated accessing of computation-heavy
accessors and such.

Now I've also noticed that `with-gensyms` is used *inside* the produced
body.  That's almost certainly wrong.  Consider the expansion of
`pop-first-char`:

```
(let ((x "foo")) (pop-first-char x)))

=>

(LET ((X "foo"))
  (LET ((C (GENSYM)))
    (IF (> (LENGTH X) 0)
        (PROGN
         (SETQ C (SCHAR X 0))
         (IF (> (LENGTH X) 1)
             (SETQ X (SUBSEQ X 1))
             (SETQ X ""))))
    C))
```

`gensym` is called *every time* this form is evaluated, bound to `c` and
then `c` is still assigned later and returned.  It's not harmful in this
case, because there's no forms passed into the macro that are spliced in
below it.  I'll explain below how this should be rewritten instead.

---

So, going definition by definition:

- `starts-with-p` is inefficient as you can just compare from the start
  and abort early if there's no match.  The comparison can also be
  `(eql 0 p)` which will work in all circumstances.
- `pop-first-char` is, as explained, not quite so well written.
  `with-gensyms` isn't needed and it should fail if there's nothing in
  the string in the first place instead of returning a `gensym` symbol.
  Also, `(if ... (progn))` is better written as `(when ... ...)` or
  using `cond` and `schar` should probably be `char`, `aref` or even
  `elt` as this pattern works for all sequences, not just strings.
  Consider this instead:

  ```
  (defmacro pop-first-char (place)
    (with-gensyms (s)
      `(let ((,s ,place))
         (prog1 (schar ,s 0)
           (setf ,place (subseq ,s 1))))))
  ```

  This will at least behave more consistently with respect to empty
  strings (error) and evaluates `place` only as often as necessary.
- `pop-chars` can also be written much more efficiently.  The
  combination of `pop-first-char`, which will copy the rest of the
  string and the loop introduces unnecessary quadratic behaviour; it
  would be much better, say, to `subseq` the range you want, then
  `coerce` that to a list and assign the rest.
- `format-ansi-codes` looks okayish, but note that the operations aren't
  the most efficient (`nreverse` on the result, allocating in the right
  order is likely allocating less memory).
- `kv-lookup` uses `eql` on strings - that's not working, compare the
  [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm).
  You want `equal` or `string-equal` on the strings.  Then again, I'd
  consider this behaviour an unnecessary feature.
- `format-ansi-escaped-arg` could use `typecase`.
- In `while-pop` the `seq` isn't used (which SBCL tells you when loading
  the file.  The `progn` isn't necessary and can be simplified away.
  IMO `do` is notoriously hard to understand, so I'd recommend not using
  it.  The parameters are badly named as `pop` only works on lists.
  `sequence` (which should be `list`) should also be assigned to a
  temporary variable.

I'll stop here; you get the gist of it by following the first examples.

---

Now for your question, I dislike the optional docstring feature because
it makes implementation more complicated since you'll always be checking
if there's a literal string coming afterwards.  Having a straightforward
way to mark individual tests with a macro is completely obvious to the
reader and the developer, so I'd rather go with that.

In case you really wanted to go ahead, either consider a pattern
matching library, or don't do the whole `while-pop` thing and loop over
the list with one token lookahead, i.e.
`(next-form possibly-a-string-here ...)`.

The other general recommendation is to decompose your functionality into
functions.  Then for one testing becomes a bit easier as you can just
invoke the functions normally instead of having to `macroexpand` or
whatever your editor does, but also it allows you to demarcate the
different steps clearly by naming your functions (and documenting them
of course).

Comment: I'm afraid I entirely forgot about this question, because there is no email notification option. Also I've advanced significantly since then, and would be unlikely to make these mistakes in future. But your answer was detailed and informative; and I especially like the optimisation tips you have provided. Thanks for the help!